# Linux mount NFS share

Tags: linux, boot, mount, nfs

I want to run Linux on an embedded device (mips) which has some very hard restrictions:

- only 16MB storage
- no wired ethernet (only wifi)

Good news:

- I have a working bootloader ([u-boot](https://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot))
- I also have a working kernel (version 3.10.14 #2 PREEMPT)
- and I have a working root filesystem (linux can start and I can log in)

Now the problem is that I have no more space left to run any user application on this hardware, that's why I want to move towards NFS.

Here I'm not sure about the procedure.

Boot process is handled by U-boot as I have mentioned. But U-boot is not able to initialize the Wifi - hence I will need some small Linux OS for this purpose.

### Main idea

1. U-boot loads the kernel and starts it
2. Kernel contains drivers for the wifi chip and it mounts the rootfs
3. rootfs contains the necessary files for connecting to AP (passwords, ssid, etc)
4. once the connection is up, NFS will mount the remote fs to /opt or something

**Is it somehow possible to replace the root (/) filesystem with the one lays on NFS? (In spite of the fact that wifi config is stored on this partition which was needed to start the connection)**

### Update

I have successfully compiled nfs client programs for mips and the device is now able to mount the new rootfs via nfs into some directory, however *pivot_root* fails:

```
# mount -o nolock IPADDRESS:/srv/fs /tmp/nfs
# ls /tmp/nfs
bin
etc
...
# ls /tmp
nfs
old
# pivot_root /tmp/nfs /tmp/old
pivot_root: Invalid argument
# pivot_root
BusyBox v1.29.0.git (2018-06-23 20:08:52 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: pivot_root NEW_ROOT PUT_OLD

Move the current root file system to PUT_OLD and make NEW_ROOT the new root file system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes – and you're basically doing the same thing as an initramfs does on Linux PCs. The initramfs starts like a normal root filesystem on an in-memory `/` rootfs; then it mounts the real root filesystem somewhere at /mnt or /real.

(This is actually often used to implement NFS-root on servers, in situations where the kernel's built-in NFS support is insufficient – e.g. when Kerberos is needed.)

- The important step is using the **[pivot_root()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html)** syscall to swap the current root with the newly mounted one. After the call, the original rootfs still remains mounted, but no longer at / – the call moves the mount to a subdirectory of the "new" rootfs.

  There is also a [`pivot_root` program](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pivot_root.8.html) in Busybox (as well as in util-linux) which can be used if your init process is a shellscript (as is often the case). The linked util-linux manual page has examples of its usage.
- Alternatively, according to [Linus](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/pivot_root.html), it can be enough to simply **[chroot()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html)** into the newly mounted root – that is, if you no longer need access to the original root. Again, there is a `chroot` command-line tool for that.

---

Note: You do not *need* to build and use an initramfs to achieve this; the functions don't care whether they're called from an initrd image or from a real rootfs.

However, because a "normal" initramfs runs from a temporary in-memory unpacked filesystem, it is customary for tools like `switch_root` to delete all of the initramfs files right before pivoting to the new root. But if you're directly booting from an on-disk filesystem, this probably *not* what you want, so be sure to not use the `switch_root` tool, only `pivot_root`.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. If the nfs will disconnect (due to network errors), is there any chance to get back to the previous rootfs, to gracefully shutdown or restart?

Comment: Technically, yes, if you used pivot_root and didn't unmount the old root afterwards, then you can of course pivot (or chroot) back into it... assuming the necessary tools are still available in memory. But more likely everything will just block waiting for the NFS server for respond.

Comment: pivot_root is not working, and I couldn't make it more verbose. chroot was a bit more successful, rootfs is changed however is there any way to preserve the dynamic directories during this operation? (i.e. /proc, /sys, /dev)?

Comment: Just mount them anew under the new root, or `mount --bind` / `mount --rbind` the existing ones into the new location, before chrooting. (That's what e.g. `arch-chroot` does in Arch Linux.)

Comment: Note that for pivot_root, the PUT_OLD location must be _within the new root_ (the reasons should become obvious after thinking about it). So if the new root is at /tmp/new, put_old has to be e.g. /tmp/new/old or such. See also the manual page [from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pivot_root.8.html).

Comment: What a silly mistake. Thanks! I have now accepted your answer as it fulfills my desires.